# drupal 7 $query->where and DATE_FORMAT not recognized

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views

I have implement a function views_query_alter.
I want to add a where clause. 
I try with : $query->add_where(0, "DATE_FORMAT(myfieldname, '%Y-%m-%d')", "DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')", '>');

I also try with condition.
The result printed sql is the same from both cases and is DATE_FORMATmyfieldnameYmd. Is there any way to escaped a DATE_FORMAT or anything to succesfully recognized DATE_FORMAT function into where clause?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

dont know if you found a solution but the following works for me

```
$query->add_where_expression(0, "DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myfieldname.value, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m') > 'value'");
```